# react navigation 5.x with react native firebase getInitialNotification method

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, push-notification, react-navigation

I am using react native firebase `getInitialNotification` method to handle push notification when the app is `killed` (totally closed and is not in background). I want to navigate the user to a desired screen when the user taps on the push notification.

**Current behaviour:**
The push notification is always received but the navigation is not stable, sometimes work, sometimes does not.

What do I mean by **not working:**  The app opens and show me the home screen, the navigation does not occur.

**Expected behaviour**:
As a user, when I tap on the push notification on the status bar, the app will open and navigate to a desired screen.

I am initializing the the firebase listeners in `App.tsx`:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(this.handleSelected);
    messaging().onMessage(this.handleOnMessage);
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(this.handleSelected);
    RNBootSplash.hide();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppContainer/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Remarks:
Where do I initialize the `NavigationContainer`? In `AppContainer` as follow:

```
export default function AppContainer() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigatorRef}>
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}>
        {isLoggedIn ? (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppStack}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthorizationStack}/>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthorizationStack}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppStack}/>
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Where do I handle the navigation? In `handleOnMessage` method, using `navigate` object.

Does the navigation works when the app is open in the **background**? yes always works perfectly. (As you can see in the code, I am using `onNotificationOpenedApp` for that)

**My hypothesis according to my observation**:

- I am using `"react-native-bootsplash"`, maybe this can have conflict with firebase listeners when the app opens from killed state.
- I am using `"@react-navigation/stack"`, maybe I am initializing the firebase listeners before the `NavigationContainer` is initialized.

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^7.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.1.1",
    "react-native-bootsplash": "^2.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.16"
```

Comment: Do you have the answer yourself? I'm having the similar issue.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I'm having the same situation and I can't solve that :/